# Objectify order() requires ancestor()?

Tags: java, objectify, ancestor

I have an entity that contain @Parent

```
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    private             String          instID;

    // This has to stay String, because GAE doesn't take custom type
    @Index
    @Parent
    private             Ref<Partner>    ownerRef;

    @Index
    private             Date            createdOn;
}
```

When I tried query for all of the latest MyObject, by running...

```
ofy().load()
     .type(MyObject.class)
     .order("-createdOn")
     .limit(10)
     .list();
```

I got zero record back...however, if I comment out the .order() part, I got the record returned.  I wonder if the order() requires ancestor().

Anyone knows?

Comment: So I modified the load statement() to include ancestor(), and it works...but it  introduces a problem, because what I really want is to select the top 10 records despite what the parent is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Parent and ancestor() are red herrings. Your query should work as-is. Are you certain you saved the entity with the @Index field applied? If you add @Index, you need to resave an entity to establish the index.

Querying without filters always works - it always returns every entity. Filtering requires a live index.

Comment: stickfigure...you nailed it on the head again...I just removed all my test data and started fresh and the query works.  So the answer to my question is "No, one won't need to call the ancestor() when using order()"  Thanks again!